# javax.el.ELException: /converter.xhtml @44,53 value="#{converterBean.toList}": Error reading 'toList' on type com.primesystems.beans.ConverterBean

Tags: jsf

I am running a JSF app in Tomcat. It has 3 lists which are linked by the `render` attribute.

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="selectedCategory" value="#{converterBean.selectedCategory}">
    <f:ajax execute="selectedCategory" render="selectedFrom"/>
    <f:selectItems value="#{converterBean.categories}"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
<h:selectOneListbox id="selectedFrom" value="#{converterBean.selectedFrom}" size="5">
    <f:selectItems value="#{converterBean.fromList}"/>
    <f:ajax execute="selectedCategory selectedFrom" render="selectedTo"/>
</h:selectOneListbox>
<h:selectOneListbox id="selectedTo" value="#{converterBean.selectedTo}" size="5">
    <f:selectItems value="#{converterBean.toList}"/>
</h:selectOneListbox>
```

When I click `selectedCategory` it renders `selectedFrom` fine.  When I select item in `selectedFrom` it gives error as below.

> SEVERE: javax.el.ELException: /converter.xhtml @44,53 value="#{converterBean.toList}": Error reading 'toList' on type com.primesystems.beans.ConverterBean

I would like to get more stack trace but running in debugger, adding log4j for tomcat related appenders and surrounding my bean method with try/catch is no good.

I have tried mojarra versions 2.1.7 and 2.2.0-m05 both have same behavior.

**There was issue with my code and catching exception in converterBean.getToList method I was able to capture the stack trace.  So issue I had is resolved.**

I would like comment on below though.  locater below is injected into converter bean and since the Conveter class is not serializable I added logic as below since I saw exceptions related to serialization at times.

```
@ManagedBean(name="serviceLocater")
@ApplicationScoped
public class LocalServiceLocater implements ServiceLocater, Serializable {
transient private Converter converter;
public LocalServiceLocater() {
    converter = new Converter();
}
public Converter getConverter() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return converter;
}

private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream in)
        throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        in.defaultReadObject();
        converter = new Converter();
}

}
```

I would also like to add one more question to same.  When I select *category*, the *from list* and *to list* both need to update.  Currently I have coded them hoping that they cascade but it updates only *from list*. I have attempted rendering both *from* and *to list* in *category ajax render attribute*  but then it sends *category, old from* while I want it to make two requests instead.  first with *category* to fill *from list*.  The 2nd request with *category, from* to fill the *to list*.

Comment: Please lookup the full stacktrace and post it. The answer is in there. Note that the bug is just in your own code, not in Mojarra. The `getToList()` method threw an exception (which should be visible as "root cause"/"caused by" part down in the stacktrace). Instead of the stacktrace you can also just post the relevant backing bean code so that we can point out your mistake for you.

Comment: @BalusC I am unable to get more stack trace.  I have tried wrapping the code with try/catch, added log4j to webapp with tomcat related config, tried running in debugger in tomcat/eclipse but not able to get to point where I get to stack trace.  Thanks for cleanup.

Comment: @BalusC as per your judgement I was able to catch stack trace by using try/catch in getList method.  I fixed issue and have few more questions added especially on how to cascade the rendering.